# Using SearchBar with ObservableCollection in MVVM

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I've created a search page in my app and I'd like to be able to search through my `ObservableCollection` of items in the ViewModel and display them onto a `CollectionView`. So far this is what I've done and I get an exception i.e `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'` every time I run the app.
**SearchPage XAML**

```
<!--Doctors Search Result-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding RecentDoctors}">

                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <ListItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpacing="15"/>
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <!--Image-->
                            <Frame BackgroundColor="Black"
                                   HeightRequest="20"
                                   WidthRequest="20"
                                   CornerRadius="100"
                                   Margin="20,0,0,0"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   IsClippedToBounds="True">

                                <Image HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                            </Frame>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                                         VerticalOptions="Center"
                                         Spacing="-3">
                                <!--Fullname-->
                                <Label Text="{Binding DoctorsName}"
                                       FontSize="19"
                                       FontAttributes="Bold"/>

                                <!--Specialization-->
                                <Label Text="{Binding Specialization}"
                                       FontSize="14"
                                       TextColor="LightGray"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </Grid>

        <!--Doctors Search Bar-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
            <pancake:PancakeView BackgroundColor="#0F8DF4"
                                 HasShadow="True">
                <Grid>
                    <!--The SearchBar-->
                    <renderers:CustomSearchBar x:Name="doctorsSearchBar"
                               Placeholder="Search Doctors by Name, Specialization"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               FontSize="17"
                               TextColor="Black"
                               WidthRequest="320"
                               Text="{Binding SearchedText}"
                               SearchCommand="{Binding SearchBarCommand}"
                               SearchCommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference doctorsSearchBar}}"/>
                </Grid>
            </pancake:PancakeView>
        </Grid>
```

**SearchPage ViewModel**

```
public class TelemedSearchPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private string _searchedText;
        public string SearchedText
        {
            get { return _searchedText; }

            set
            {
                _searchedText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                Search();
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<RecentDoctorsInfo> RecentDoctors { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<RecentDoctorsInfo>();

        public ICommand SearchBarCommand { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Main Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public TelemedSearchPageViewModel()
        {
            SearchBarCommand = new RelayCommand(Search);

            //RecentDoctorsList
            RecentDoctors.Add(new RecentDoctorsInfo()
            {
                DoctorsName = "Steven Strange",
                Specialization = "Sorcerer Supreme",
                Location = "177a Bleecker St. | USA"
            });

            RecentDoctors.Add(new RecentDoctorsInfo()
            {
                DoctorsName = "Peter Parker",
                Specialization = "Spiderman",
                Location = "177a Bleecker St. | USA"
            });

            RecentDoctors.Add(new RecentDoctorsInfo()
            {
                DoctorsName = "Bruce Banner",
                Specialization = "The Hulk",
                Location = "177a Bleecker St. | USA"
            });

            RecentDoctors.Add(new RecentDoctorsInfo()
            {
                DoctorsName = "Reed Richards",
                Specialization = "Mr.Fantastic",
                Location = "177a Bleecker St. | USA"
            });  
        }

        #region METHODS
        public void Search()
        {
            if (RecentDoctors != null && RecentDoctors.Count >0)
            {
                var temp = RecentDoctors.Where(x => x.DoctorsName.ToLower().Contains(SearchedText.ToLower()));

                foreach (var item in temp)
                {
                    RecentDoctors.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

**Edit3:**

```
if (RecentDoctors != null && RecentDoctors.Count > 0)
            {
                var results = RecentDoctors.Where(x => x.DoctorsName.ToLower().Contains(SearchedText.ToLower()));
                SearchResults.Clear();
                foreach (RecentDoctorsInfo item in results)
                {
                    SearchResults.Add(item);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                RecentDoctors.Clear();
            }
```

Comment: which line is causing the exception, and what is the InnerException value?

Comment: In the `SearchedText` property, whenever I comment out the `Search();` method the exception is not thrown but the search function also doesn't work. So I believe that line is the problem. And I do not know where to find this "InnerException value".

Comment: Search is searching RecentDoctors AND adding the results BACK to RecentDoctors.  That is probably causing an exception

Comment: So instead of searching and adding it back how should it be done? I realized that the exception is thrown as soon as I start typing

Comment: what you're doing doesn't make any sense logically.  You're searching list A for something and if you find it you're adding it to A again.  That doesn't do anything useful.  Usually with a use case like this you have two lists - the complete list of data (A), and the search results (B).  You search A and add any results to B.  Then you change your CollectionView's ItemSource to B.  There are a couple of variations of this you could use, but that's the basic concept.

Comment: Ok, if you check I've edited the last part like so. I think I get what you mean. The exception isn't being thrown anymore but now when I search no results or hits pop up, am I doing something wrong. Edited code is in original post btw.

Comment: Are you assigning SearchResults to anything?  Are you sure your query is returning results?

Comment: Ok, I've re-edited the code and placed SearchResults outside the method and made it a property. Now the search function is working, but it's kinda funky... An item is added for each and every letter that is typed, this is resulting in a multitude of the same results. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: You need to clear the results every time you execute you query

Comment: ok last one, after searching, when I clear the query, instead of the CollectionView staying blank, it lists all of the members. How can I keep it staying blank after search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute the search when user type you should use a behavior as doscs suggest

```
public class SearchBarTextChangedBehavior : Behavior<SearchBar>
{
    protected override void OnAttachedTo(SearchBar bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        bindable.TextChanged += this.SearchBar_TextChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(SearchBar bindable)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        bindable.TextChanged -= this.SearchBar_TextChanged;
    }

    private void SearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((SearchBar)sender).SearchBarCommand?.Execute(e.NewTextValue);
    }
}
```

Then attach the behavior to your `SearchBar`

```
<renderers:CustomSearchBar
    x:Name="doctorsSearchBar"
    Placeholder="Search Doctors by Name, Specialization"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    FontSize="17"
    TextColor="Black"
    WidthRequest="320"
    Text="{Binding SearchedText}"
    SearchCommand="{Binding SearchBarCommand}">
    <renderers:CustomSearchBar.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:SearchBarTextChangedBehavior />
    </renderers:CustomSearchBar.Behaviors>
</renderers:CustomSearchBar>
```

By the other hand, you should create a private copy of the original list and add the same items as the public collection

```
private List<RecentDoctorsInfo> originalRecentDoctorsList = new List<RecentDoctorsInfo>();

public ObservableCollection<RecentDoctorsInfo> RecentDoctors { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<RecentDoctorsInfo>();

public ICommand SearchBarCommand { get; set; }

public TelemedSearchPageViewModel()
{
    SearchBarCommand = new RelayCommand(Search);

    //RecentDoctorsList
    RecentDoctors.Add(new RecentDoctorsInfo()
    {
        DoctorsName = "Steven Strange",
        Specialization = "Sorcerer Supreme",
        Location = "177a Bleecker St. | USA"
    });

    RecentDoctors.Add(new RecentDoctorsInfo()
    {
        DoctorsName = "Peter Parker",
        Specialization = "Spiderman",
        Location = "177a Bleecker St. | USA"
    });

    RecentDoctors.Add(new RecentDoctorsInfo()
    {
        DoctorsName = "Bruce Banner",
        Specialization = "The Hulk",
        Location = "177a Bleecker St. | USA"
    });

    RecentDoctors.Add(new RecentDoctorsInfo()
    {
        DoctorsName = "Reed Richards",
        Specialization = "Mr.Fantastic",
        Location = "177a Bleecker St. | USA"
    });

    // Backup copy list.
    originalRecentDoctorsList.Add(new RecentDoctorsInfo()
    {
        DoctorsName = "Steven Strange",
        Specialization = "Sorcerer Supreme",
        Location = "177a Bleecker St. | USA"
    });

    originalRecentDoctorsList.Add(new RecentDoctorsInfo()
    {
        DoctorsName = "Peter Parker",
        Specialization = "Spiderman",
        Location = "177a Bleecker St. | USA"
    });

    originalRecentDoctorsList.Add(new RecentDoctorsInfo()
    {
        DoctorsName = "Bruce Banner",
        Specialization = "The Hulk",
        Location = "177a Bleecker St. | USA"
    });

    originalRecentDoctorsList.Add(new RecentDoctorsInfo()
    {
        DoctorsName = "Reed Richards",
        Specialization = "Mr.Fantastic",
        Location = "177a Bleecker St. | USA"
    });  
}
```

And by last, your `Search` method should clean the public collection (the one you're showing) and use the private as backup

```
private void Search()
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchedText))
    {
        var filteredDoctors = RecentDoctors
                    .Where(x =>
                        x.DoctorsName.ToLower().Contains(SearchedText.ToLower()))
                    .ToList();

        RecentDoctors.Clear();

        foreach(var recentDoctor in filteredDoctors)
            RecentDoctors.Add(recentDoctor);
    }
    else
    {
        // This is when you clean the text from the search

        RecentDoctors.Clear();

        foreach(var originalRecentDoctor in originalRecentDoctorsList)
            RecentDoctors.Add(originalRecentDoctor);
    }
}
```